# Error while converting JavaRDD to Dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to convert JavaRDD to Dataframe using createDataFrame(JavaRDD rdd, Class beanclass) function, but I am getting following error. I have used the following example because it's present in Spark Repo and it maps to my use-case.

**My Usecase:**

I am trying to convert a JavaRDD with a complex nested object(with enums and multilevel hashmap) to Dataframes So that I can write the data in ORC/Parquet format(JavaRDD doesn't support ORC/Parquet)

The input data is in Avro format, there is an infinite recursion problem in createDataFrame for Avro types, referring to this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25789, that's I am loading the data in JavaRDD first.

---

**Imports:**

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
```

**Pojo**

```
public enum Gender implements Serializable {
        M,
        F;
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Person implements Serializable {
        private Gender gender;
        private String name;
        private int age;
    }
```

**Creating RDD**

```
 JavaRDD<Person> peopleRDD = spark.read()
                .textFile("people.txt")
                .javaRDD()
                .map(line -> {
                    String[] parts = line.split(",");
                    Person person = new Person();
                    person.setGender(Gender.valueOf(parts[0]));
                    person.setName(parts[1]);
                    person.setAge(Integer.parseInt(parts[2].trim()));
                    return person;
                });
```

**Creating DataFrame from RDD**

```
        // Apply a schema to an RDD of JavaBeans to get a DataFrame
        Dataset<Row> peopleDF = spark.createDataFrame(peopleRDD, Person.class);
        // Register the DataFrame as a temporary view
        System.out.println(peopleDF.takeAsList(2).get(0));
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (M) of the type (com.xyz.JavaSparkSQLExample.Gender) cannot be converted to the string type
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:396)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1108)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$beansToRows$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:1106)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
```

---

I have modified the example provided in Spark Repo: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/JavaSparkSQLExample.java

Comment: why aren't you reading from CSV format directly if Spark supports it already? You can either provide the schema then or let Spark infer it.

Comment: @UninformedUser The input Data is in Avro, there is Infinite recursion problem in createDataFrame for Avro types, referring to this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-25789